# Deploy app on shinyapp.io that uses content from my google drive

Tags: r, shiny, google-drive-api, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy a shiny app via shinyapp.io. Unfortunately I am completely new to shiny and this is my first project. Basically, what the app is supposed to do is read a google spreadsheet that I keep in my google drive and do some analysis on the content which I then want to provide to somebody else.

I can give you the code I am using, since it's fairly short:

```
packages <- c("shiny", "googlesheets4", "googledrive", "tidyr")

lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage("Just some test title",
                textOutput("test_output"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$total <-renderText({df <- drive_get("Desired_SpreadSheet") %>%
    read_sheet(sheet = "Desired Sheet") %>% drop_na()
    test_output = sum(df$numeric_column)
    print(paste0("This should be some number: ", test_output))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And if I run this locally, I get the desired output. However, when I try deploying via shinyapp.io by using the following code:

```
rsconnect::deployApp(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
```

The dashboard just features the right title and then the error message

**Error**: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

So I conclude, he deployment works for all lines that do not require content from the google spreadsheet but somehow accessing this sheet does not work. Also I don't even know how to access the logs for this to debug myself.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions how to fix this!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the logs by going to shinyapps and logging in. There will be a dashboard with your apps and a tab for the logs.

However, I suspect the problem is that ShinyApps doesn't have the authorisation to access your Google Drive / Google Sheet, so you need to set that up.

I struggled with this myself but got it working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051305/struggling-to-use-my-own-api-key-with-googlesheets4-in-shinyapps-io).

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely the issue I had!